# app crash due to array error

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am having a rough time diagnosing an app crash. I have reviewed the Debug navigator but I am not sure how to read all of the information.  Here is what I have.

In the code I get this error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0
```

In the debug nav, I see this:

```
3 DispenseScreenTwoViewController.prepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue, sender : AnyObject!) -> ()
```

When I mouse over the variable array I have created to be transferred to the next view controller I see this:

```
@"6 objects"
```

The six objects are the items I have populated the array with and here is where I think my issue might be. When I click on the Info icon, the following prints to the logs. I clicked on one of the array items (array item 1). The debugger shows the correct value (Joe Black) but then as I drill down, I see a read memory error. The [0] value of the array does not return that error. However, two of the other six values of the array DO return the same read memory error.

Here is the text from the logs as I click on the Info icon for item 1 of the array:

```
Printing description of ((NSTaggedPointerString *)0xa3b0c03ef0883929):
Joe Black
Printing description of (*( (NSString *)0xa3b0c03ef0883929)):
(NSString) NSString = {
  NSObject = {
    isa = <read memory from 0xa3b0c03ef0883929 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>

 }

}

Printing description of (*( (NSObject *)0xa3b0c03ef0883929)):
(NSObject) NSObject = {
  isa = <read memory from 0xa3b0c03ef0883929 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>

}

Printing description of :
(Class) isa = <read memory from 0xa3b0c03ef0883929 failed (0 of 8 bytes     read)>
```

Here is my code that creates the array and the `prepareForSegue` function:

```
if blankData != 1 {
            //add code to pass data to next veiw controller
            enteredDataArrayTwo = [toPassTwo, enterPersonnelName.text!, enterDrugID.text!, enterPackageNumber.text!, enterQty.text!, enterExpDate.text!]
            print(enteredDataArrayTwo)
            self.appIsWorking()
            performSegueWithIdentifier("goToDispenseScreenThree", sender: self)
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goToDispenseScreenThree") {
        //Checking identifier is crucial as there might be multiple segues attached to same view
        let DestViewControllerThree = segue.destinationViewController as! DispenseScreenThreeViewController;
        DestViewControllerThree.toPassThree = enteredDataArrayTwo as! [String]
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that all the console says? Usually it's a really long description and starts off with: "App crashed due to NSException: ...." what else does it say?

Comment: I apologize for this but I am at a loss to find what you are speaking of. I have moused over and clicked on everything I can see in the Debug Navigator and I don't see anything that starts with "app crashed due to..." This is my first project, actually my first every attempt at coding, so I could use a point in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: The console at the bottom should display the error messages when the app crashes.

Comment: I do not see anything like "app crashed due to..." in the console. Here is a [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q1dv5qz5nt250bg/2015-09-21%20at%201.21%20PM.png?dl=0)

Comment: @JozemiteApps Again, I apologize for what may be a very elementary questions. I have been looking on the Apple Developer site about debugging and I still cannot find anything. The one item that comes up in the console is "(lldb)". That seem a long way from "app crashed due to..." Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmmm... I meant that when I get errors, I usually get errors like this on my console. It states the reason why it crashes. This is a game crashing but I've gotten this same error input into the console when I did it on a regular app. This is how my xCode looks. [screenshot](http://imgur.com/BVaHRus). Notice on the bottom how my error states why it crashed. It might just be that your type of error is different than mine so it won't show like that.

Comment: @JozemiteApps I am still working on this. I have been combing over the debugger and I have found something interesting. in the `func prepareForSegue` the value of `DestViewControllerThree.toPassThree` is supposed to be = `enteredDataArrayTwo`. However, when I look at the debugger [THIS] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/rcb2o8pimmu9n8t/2015-09-23%20at%203.00%20PM.png?dl=0) is what I see. Should that var populate in the `prepareForSegue` func or after the app is passed to the next view?

Comment: I have also been searching for (lldb) and I see many posts about an unexpected nil value being the cause.  I also see many about a bug in Xcode? Hard to know which it is (if not both).